# Is there a way to query the Apple System Log incrementally?

Tags: objective-c, macos, syslog

I want to display some contents of the system log using the Apple System Log API. Is there a way to query the log database incrementally, ie. only get the messages that are new since the last query? The `aslresponse_next` call only seems to iterate over messages that existed at the time of the query.

I think I could fake incremental querying by setting a minimum time filter, but the approach seems prone to various timing issues, so I’d rather have something more official if possible.